# How to view all data based on link id in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter. I am getting values from database into jobs page. In jobs page I am showing only three columns from jobs table from database. I have a link button as 'View More'. When user clicks on view-more link, then I want to show all job details based on it's id in viewjobs page.

How can I get id from jobs page to viewjobs page to display all data from jobs table from database? How can I get values in controller?

Please check my jobs controller code

```
class Careers extends CI_Controller {
  public function jobs()
  {   
    $this->load->database();  
    $this->load->model('xjobs');  
    $data['h']=$this->xjobs->xjobslist();  
    $this->load->view('jobs', $data);  
  } 
}
```

Here is my jobs.php code from view.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped jobtable">
  <thead style="background:#f4ae00; color:#fff; border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;">
    <tr>
      <th height="30" style="font-weight:400; font-size:18px;">Company Name</th>
      <th style="font-weight:400; font-size:18px;">Job Title</th>
      <th style="font-weight:400; font-size:18px;">Location</th>
      <th style="font-weight:400; font-size:18px;">View</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php  
    foreach ($h->result() as $row)  
    {
?>
      <tr>
        <td height="60" style="padding-top:15px;"><?php echo $row->company; ?></td>
        <td style="padding-top:15px;"><?php echo $row->position; ?></td>
        <td style="padding-top:15px;"><?php echo $row->location; ?></td>
        <td style="padding-top:15px;">
          <a href='<?php echo base_url() ?>careers/viewjob?id=<?php echo $row->id; ?>&<?php echo $row->company; ?>&<?php echo $row->location; ?>' class='apply-btn'>View More</a>
        </td>  
      </tr>
<?php                                                                 
    }
?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: do you want to show all the job detail on the same page or another page?

Comment: in another page

Comment: what is the issue in this line `<td style="padding-top:15px;"><a href='<?php echo base_url() ?>careers/viewjob?id=<?php echo $row->id; ?>&<?php echo $row->company; ?>&<?php echo $row->location; ?>' class='apply-btn'>View More</a></td>`?

Comment: how can get all data in another page based on its id <?php echo $row->id; ?>

Comment: Just call controller function with `$id`. Get all data based on that id and load the job detail view. Let me answer

Comment: I need code how to get this id in controller, can you please explain in detail

Comment: See my answer and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$row->id` to get all the data from the controller

```
<td style="padding-top:15px;"><a href="<?= base_url('careers/viewjob/'. $row->id) ?>" class='apply-btn'>View More</a></td>
```

**Controller**

```
public function viewjob($id){
 $this->load->model('xjobs');  
 $data['detail']=$this->xjobs->jobdetail($id);  
 $this->load->view('filename', $data); 
}
```

**Model**

```
public function  jobdetail($id){
    return $this->db->get_where('table', ['column' => $id])->row();
}
```